# How to use handle(w, “flag”) with Julia, WebIO & Blink?

Tags: user-interface, julia

I'm trying to use Blink with Julia (1.02) to create a simple login page.

I have a working login_button and a handler function (I think) for button presses, but I cannot get the functions inside the "handle(w, "press") do args..." to do anything useful.

I'd like the handler function to run "body!(w, new_page)" after checking the username & password, but it just hangs after printing out "login_button pressed!" after which the button stops responding.

I've been struggling with this for some time now, any help is appreciated.

Old Julia Code:

```
using WebIO, Blink

page =
  node(:div,
    node(:p, "please login below.", attributes=Dict("class"=>"lead")),
    node(:input, attributes=Dict("id"=>"username", "type"=>"text", "placeholder"=>"username")),
    node(:input, attributes=Dict("id"=>"password", "type"=>"password", "placeholder"=>"password")),
    node(:button, "LOGIN", attributes=Dict("id"=>"login_button")));

new_page = node(:div, "New page!");

w = Window()
body!(w, page)

@js_ w document.getElementById("login_button").onclick = () -> Blink.msg("press", "login")

handle(w, "press") do args...
    println("login_button pressed!")

    username = @js w document.querySelector("""input[id="username"]""").value
    password = @js w document.querySelector("""input[id="password"]""").value

    println("$username, $password")

    if username == "user" && password == "pass"
        body!(w, new_page)
    else
        @js alert("Incorrect username or password. Try again.")
    end
end
```

New Code:

```
using WebIO, Blink, Interact
using ..User

function page_inputs()
    username = textbox("enter username", attributes=Dict("size"=>50))
    password = textbox("enter password", typ="password")
    login_button = button("LOGIN")
    Widget(["username"=>username,"password"=>password,"login_button"=>login_button])
end

inputs = page_inputs();

page =
  node(:div,
    node(:br),
    node(:img, attributes=Dict("src"=>"https://elmordyn.files.wordpress.com/2012/07/20110223084209-beholder.gif")),
    node(:h2, "beholder", attributes=Dict("class"=>"display-3")),
    node(:p, "VERSION 0.2"),
    node(:hr, attributes=Dict("class"=>"my-3")),
    node(:p, "No unauthorized access. Please login below.", attributes=Dict("class"=>"lead")),
    node(:div, inputs),
        attributes=Dict(:align=>"middle"));

title = "LOGIN ~ beholdia"
size = (500, 600)

function validate_user(w, inputs)
    if inputs["login_button"][] > 0

        inputs["login_button"][] = 0

        if inputs["username"][] in keys(User.users) && inputs["password"][] == User.users[inputs["username"][]]
            println("""Logging $(inputs["username"][]) in...""")
            return true
        else
            @js w alert("Incorrect username or password. Try again.")
            return false
        end
    end
end

function events(w, inputs)
    @async while true
        validate_user(w, inputs) == true ? break : sleep(0.1)
    end
end
```

Comment: Hey Dustin, Can you edit your question above and include what you want to do that isn't working, just so I can compare that against what is working!

Comment: @ logankilpatrick Thanks for taking a look at this. I've re-written a bit of the code using WebIO but I'm still having the same problem. I also tried replacing the inputs with a custom Interact Widget, but kept running into errors there too. I'm at a loss here.

Comment: Hi all, thanks for your responses! I decided to go any entirely different direction with this and use an async while loop to check Interact observables and trigger functions. Functioning code is posted below the original code. :)